# Modify repeating word/text in txt file based on matching text/parameter(s)

Tags: .net, json, regex, batch-file, vbscript

I have a text file, containing:

```
[{
      "Subtitle": {
        "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
        },
        "SubtitleList": [
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 3,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
        }]
    }
}]
```

However, this same structure can be repeated multiple times throughout the file, while always following the same structure.

Under **"SubtitleList"**, I want to make sure that it is always the case that **"Default": true**, while **"ID": 1** and **"Track": 0**.

Else If ID and Track equal anything else ( e.g. "ID": 2 and "Track": 1 or something similar), then default should be false.

I think this needs a for loop, or an if then else.

Here is an example of the **entire** file:

```
[
  {
    "Job": {
      "Audio": {
        "AudioList": [
          {
            "Bitrate": 448,
            "DRC": 0.0,
            "Encoder": "ac3",
            "Gain": 0.0,
            "Mixdown": 7,
            "NormalizeMixLevel": false,
            "Samplerate": 0,
            "Track": 0,
            "DitherMethod": 0
          }
        ],
        "CopyMask": [
          "copy:aac",
          "copy:mp3"
        ],
        "FallbackEncoder": "ac3"
      },
      "Destination": {
        "ChapterList": [
          {
            "Name": "00:00:00.000"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:03:43.723"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:10:31.756"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:13:25.847"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:17:38.641"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:19:35.841"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:25:12.302"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:28:01.305"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:35:09.065"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:43:07.084"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:49:29.592"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:52:14.214"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:59:24.978"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:02:53.728"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:15:50.921"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:21:28.801"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:24:23.183"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:31:45.875"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:35:52.664"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:44:06.282"
          }
        ],
        "ChapterMarkers": true,
        "AlignAVStart": false,
        "File": "C:\\Temp\\ExampleFixed.mkv",
        "Mp4Options": {
          "IpodAtom": false,
          "Mp4Optimize": false
        },
        "Mux": "mkv"
      },
      "Filters": {
        "FilterList": [
          {
            "ID": 4,
            "Settings": {
              "mode": "7"
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "Settings": {
              "block-height": "16",
              "block-thresh": "40",
              "block-width": "16",
              "filter-mode": "2",
              "mode": "3",
              "motion-thresh": "1",
              "spatial-metric": "2",
              "spatial-thresh": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 11,
            "Settings": {
              "crop-bottom": "0",
              "crop-left": "0",
              "crop-right": "0",
              "crop-top": "0",
              "height": "404",
              "width": "720"
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 6,
            "Settings": {
              "mode": "0"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "PAR": {
        "Num": 202,
        "Den": 195
      },
      "Metadata": {},
      "SequenceID": 0,
      "Source": {
        "Angle": 1,
        "Range": {
          "Type": "chapter",
          "Start": 1,
          "End": 20
        },
        "Title": 1,
        "Path": "C:\\Temp\\Example.mkv"
      },
      "Subtitle": {
        "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
        },
        "SubtitleList": [
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 3,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      "Video": {
        "Encoder": "x265",
        "Level": "auto",
        "TwoPass": false,
        "Turbo": false,
        "ColorMatrixCode": 0,
        "Options": "level=41",
        "Preset": "fast",
        "Profile": "auto",
        "Quality": 19.0,
        "QSV": {
          "Decode": false,
          "AsyncDepth": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Job": {
      "Audio": {
        "AudioList": [
          {
            "Bitrate": 448,
            "DRC": 0.0,
            "Encoder": "ac3",
            "Gain": 0.0,
            "Mixdown": 7,
            "NormalizeMixLevel": false,
            "Samplerate": 0,
            "Track": 0,
            "DitherMethod": 0
          }
        ],
        "CopyMask": [
          "copy:aac",
          "copy:mp3"
        ],
        "FallbackEncoder": "ac3"
      },
      "Destination": {
        "ChapterList": [
          {
            "Name": "00:00:00.000"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:03:43.723"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:10:31.756"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:13:25.847"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:17:38.641"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:19:35.841"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:25:12.302"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:28:01.305"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:35:09.065"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:43:07.084"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:49:29.592"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:52:14.214"
          },
          {
            "Name": "00:59:24.978"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:02:53.728"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:15:50.921"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:21:28.801"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:24:23.183"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:31:45.875"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:35:52.664"
          },
          {
            "Name": "01:44:06.282"
          }
        ],
        "ChapterMarkers": true,
        "AlignAVStart": false,
        "File": "C:\\Temp\\SecondExample.mkv",
        "Mp4Options": {
          "IpodAtom": false,
          "Mp4Optimize": false
        },
        "Mux": "mkv"
      },
      "Filters": {
        "FilterList": [
          {
            "ID": 4,
            "Settings": {
              "mode": "7"
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "Settings": {
              "block-height": "16",
              "block-thresh": "40",
              "block-width": "16",
              "filter-mode": "2",
              "mode": "3",
              "motion-thresh": "1",
              "spatial-metric": "2",
              "spatial-thresh": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 11,
            "Settings": {
              "crop-bottom": "0",
              "crop-left": "0",
              "crop-right": "0",
              "crop-top": "0",
              "height": "404",
              "width": "720"
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 6,
            "Settings": {
              "mode": "0"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "PAR": {
        "Num": 202,
        "Den": 195
      },
      "Metadata": {},
      "SequenceID": 0,
      "Source": {
        "Angle": 1,
        "Range": {
          "Type": "chapter",
          "Start": 1,
          "End": 20
        },
        "Title": 1,
        "Path": "C:\\Temp\\SecondExample.mkv"
      },
      "Subtitle": {
        "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
        },
        "SubtitleList": [
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 3,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      "Video": {
        "Encoder": "x265",
        "Level": "auto",
        "TwoPass": false,
        "Turbo": false,
        "ColorMatrixCode": 0,
        "Options": "level=41",
        "Preset": "fast",
        "Profile": "auto",
        "Quality": 19.0,
        "QSV": {
          "Decode": false,
          "AsyncDepth": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The **"Default"** should only equal **'true' while "ID": 1** and **"Track": 0** else it should always be 'false'.

Appreciate if anyone can please help with how to structure a .bat file for this?

Comment: Are you trying to parse something like JSON via regexes

Comment: I am not so bothered how it is parsed as long as I can get it working. I figured a .bat with some Regex may be easier?

Comment: I thought so. But it is important to confirm that we are looking at JSON (which can be processed with dedicated tools) or to clarify that this is only similar to JSON. Also, if it is JSON, the JSON tag would be more useful than the regex tag.

Comment: It is  piece of text copied from a JSON using Notepad to a .txt file. Hence I figured as it can be read as plain .txt a .bat would be easier to work with in the long run.

Comment: Nope, tools designed for Json expect valid formatting, there are a bunch of [validators available online](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=json+validator) to check this.

Comment: @LotPings I amended the text in my original post to valid JSON.

Comment: @Yunnosch the original post is now correct as JSON, tested with a validator.

Comment: please don't post same questions many times. Edit the original one instead next time.

Comment: @Magoo Yes I have upvoted but the answer is incomplete as the final item of XML to be processed becomes truncated.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56199380.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "hotsection="
CALL :clear$

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem if line contains `SubtitleList` we've entered hot section
 ECHO "%%a"|FIND "SubtitleList">NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "hotsection=y"
 SET "saved="
 IF DEFINED hotsection (
  FOR /L %%r IN (100,1,999) DO IF NOT DEFINED saved IF NOT DEFINED $%%r SET "$%%r=%%a"&SET "saved=Y"
  rem if line contains `}]` or `}],` then end-of-hotsection
  SET "endhot="
  FOR /f "tokens=1delims= " %%w IN ("%%a") DO FOR %%x IN ("}]" "}],") DO IF "%%w"==%%x SET "endhot=Y"
  IF DEFINED endhot (
   rem end-of-hotsection
   rem check whether we have ID 1 and Track 0
   SET "id1="&SET "track0="
   FOR /f "tokens=1,*delims== " %%r IN ('SET $') DO (
    IF "%%s"==""ID": 1," SET "id1=Y" 
    IF "%%s"==""Track": 0" SET "track0=Y" 
   )
   rem found end-of-hotsection. now regurgitate saved lines and set `default` appropriately
   FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%r IN ('SET $') DO (
    echo "%%r"|FINDSTR /r /c:" *\"Default\":" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%r) ELSE (
     FOR /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%s IN ("%%r") DO (
      IF defined track0 (IF DEFINED id1 (ECHO %%s: true,) ELSE (ECHO %%s: false,)) ELSE (ECHO %%s: false,)
     )
    )
    CALL :clear$
    SET "hotsection="
   )
  )
 ) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:clear$
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%z In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%z="
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q56199380.txt` containing your data  and some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

Since your data contained only one `subtitlelist` block, I extended the data for testing, and assumed that should there be multiple `subtitlelist`s within a `subtitle`, then each would be separated by `}],` instead of `}]`.

Overall, the standard read-text-file structure is used, assigning each line in turn to `%%a`.

If a line contains the string `subtitlelist` then we are entering a `hot block` that is subject to change. This `hot block` persists until `}]` or `}],` is found.

Lines that are outside of a `hot block` are regurgitated by the final `echo %a`.

Those that are within the block are stored in variable `$???` where `???` is an increasing 3-digit number.

When `}]` or `}],` is detected within a block, then `endhot` is set to `y` (the methodology overcomes batch's lack of a logical-OR) and the lines stored in $* are examined for `"ID": 1,` or `"Track": 0` and appropriate flags set.

The saved lines in $* are then regurgitated, except for the line containing `"Default":` preceded by any number of spaces where *that* line is split on `:` and then reconstructed using the flags `id1` and `track0` to control the value assigned to `default`.

---

Revision after more data posted

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56199380_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "hotsection="
CALL :clear$

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem if line contains `SubtitleList` we've entered hot section
 ECHO "%%a"|FIND "SubtitleList">NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "hotsection=y"
 SET "saved="
 IF DEFINED hotsection (
  FOR /L %%r IN (100,1,999) DO IF NOT DEFINED saved IF NOT DEFINED $%%r SET "$%%r=%%a"&SET "saved=Y"
  rem if line contains `}]` or `}],` then end-of-hotsection
  SET "endhot="
  SET "endtrack="
  FOR /f "tokens=1delims= " %%w IN ("%%a") DO FOR %%x IN ("}]","},") DO IF "%%w"==%%x SET "endhot=Y"&IF "}]"==%%x SET "endtrack=Y"
  IF DEFINED endhot (
   rem end-of-hotsection
   rem check whether we have ID 1 and Track 0
   SET "id1="&SET "track0="
   FOR /f "tokens=1,*delims== " %%r IN ('SET $') DO (
    IF "%%s"==""ID": 1," SET "id1=Y" 
    IF "%%s"==""Track": 0" SET "track0=Y" 
   )
   rem found end-of-hotsection. now regurgitate saved lines and set `default` appropriately
   FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%r IN ('SET $') DO (
    echo "%%r"|FINDSTR /r /c:" *\"Default\":" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%r) ELSE (
     FOR /f "tokens=1delims=:" %%s IN ("%%r") DO (
      IF defined track0 (IF DEFINED id1 (ECHO %%s: true,) ELSE (ECHO %%s: false,)) ELSE (ECHO %%s: false,)
     )
    )
    CALL :clear$
    IF DEFINED endtrack SET "hotsection="
   )
  )
 ) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:clear$
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%z In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%z="
GOTO :EOF
```

Very few changes required.

1. I changed the setting of `filename1` to point to a file containing your revised data.
2. An extra flag `endtrack` was added to differentiate between end-of-track-description (`},`) and end-of-section (`}]`)
3. the `if`s attached to the end-of-? detection now using ``` },``}] ``` were formulated to detect whether `end-of-track` had been found
4. Only if the end-of-? detected was a `}]` will the `hotsection` flag be cleared ready for the next `subtitlelist`.

I realise now that what I've called `end[-of-]track` is actually `end-of-subtitle`. You get all the fun of adjusting the code appropriately.

Comment: I have amended the original code sample at the top to show how the ID and Track numbers increment if more than one item exists under SubtitleList, just in case it changes anything.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl and see how it goes... btw in that section IF DEFINED enddtrack SET "hotsection=" is enddtrack a typo? (double d!)

Comment: Yes - that was a typo. Fixing it uncovered a bug (the logic surrounding the setting of `endtrack`) - which I've now fixed.

Comment: It is working, although more slowly than expected - I tested with 5 input subtitles (each of these containing 2 SubtitleList items) and the entire process took 2.5mins - I actually thought it was hanging, but it was still processing. May be helpful to echo each time a subtitle is being processed to show it is still running. Is it slowing down because it is cycling back to the beginning and starting all over again from the beginning on each pass?

Comment: 1 other thing, it is only minor though. The original fie contains another section under the final SubtitleList section - this is being truncated. But only on the final item. So if there are 5 items, 4 out of 5 items are totally perfect, only the last item has the end section truncated. I have updated the above to include an example of the *entire* file, rather than just the subtitle part - to help show you the overall structure in case it makes a difference to your method of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing and manipulating JSON with regex seems like a bad idea. But I couldn't resist attempting a solution with my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044).

```
jrepl "({[^}]*\qDefault\q\s*:\s*)[a-z]+([^}]*\qID\q\s*:\s*(\d+)[^}]*\qTrack\q\s*:\s*(\d+)[^}]*})"^
      "$txt=$1 + ($3=='1' && $4=='0' ? 'true' : 'false') + $2"^
      /p "\qSubtitleList\q:\s*\[[^\]]*\]"^
      /m /xseq /jq /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

I believe the above code should be reliable as long as:

- The source file is valid JSON
- The order of the members within a SubtitleList array object does not change
- There are no nested objects or arrays within a SubtitleList array object member
- *There could be some additional restrictions I haven't thought of*

Here is some test input:

```
[
  {
    "Subtitle": {
      "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
      },
      "SubtitleList": [
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Subtitle": {
      "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
      },
      "SubtitleList": [
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And here is my output:

```
[
  {
    "Subtitle": {
      "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
      },
      "SubtitleList": [
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Subtitle": {
      "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
      },
      "SubtitleList": [
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
        },
        {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I have amended the original code sample at the top to show how the ID and Track numbers increment if more than one item exists under SubtitleList. The increments are slightly different to what you figured so just wanted to make this clearer in case it changes your code.

Comment: @StrangeThings - Shouldn't matter as long as Default should be true if and only if ID=1 and Track=0, false otherwise.